# Discord app crashes when connected to Wi-Fi on iOS 9.3.5

Tags: crash, discord

Recently my Discord app has started to crash right after the loading screen, during the loading of the friends page. The app never actually loads the friends page because either it crashes, or I turn the wifi off on my device to keep the from crashing.

Attemting to solve the problem I have restarted my device 2-3 times. I would reinstall the app except for the fact that I can't download uninstalled app if they're updated past my OS version, and I can't update that either since I am using a iPod Touch (5th generation) that cannot be upgraded past iOS 9.3.5.

Here is a screenshot of the Discord app loading screen:

[image: Discord app loading screen]

And here is a screenshot of the friends page while attempting to connect, with Wi-Fi disconnected:

[image: Friends page while attemting to connect, with wifi disconnected]

Anyone else experiencing this, and or any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the other Google searches I have done about the Discord App crashing on iOS 9.3.5, I have learned that the updates to the Discord Servers cause the older Clients to Crash..
It appears that you need to update to iOS 10.x.x to update the Discord Client..

I'm having the same issues..  My iPad 3 won't work with Discord anymore..

MarkO

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with my discord, I read [this post](https://droidtheory.com/fix-discord-keeps-crashing/) which suggest updating os to the latest version. It really fixed the issue, try updating your os version to the latest this might help you.